# FuzzyWuzzy on 2 col from different DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, similarity

I have a very easy but not simple(to me at least!) question
I have 2 DFs:

```
df1:
Account_Name
samsung
tesla
microsoft

df2:
Company_name
samsung electronics
samsung Ltd
tesla motors
Microsoft corporation
```

all I am trying to do is to  find the best match for every row in df1 from df2 and also have an extra column that will tell me the similarity score for the best match found from df2.

I have got the  code that allows me to compare the 2 columns and produce the similarity score but I have no clue how to iterate through df2 to find the best match for the row in question from df1

the similarity score code is below just in case but I don't think it is relevant to this question

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

for col in ['Account_Name']:
df[f"{col}_score"] = df.apply(lambda x: similar(x["Company_name"], x[col]) * 100 if 
pd.notna(x[col]) else np.nan, axis=1)
```

The main issue is with finding the best similarity match when the data is in 2 separate DFs
help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposition based on an [*answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75311609/16120011) I made a few days ago :

```
from difflib import get_close_matches, SequenceMatcher
​
def match(word, l):
    m = get_close_matches(word, l, n=1, cutoff=0.4)
    if m:
        closest_match = m[0]
        score = SequenceMatcher(None, word, closest_match).ratio()
        return closest_match, score
    return None, 0.0
​
​
cross = df1.merge(df2, how="cross")
​
l_matches = [match(x, list(cross["Company_name"])) for x in cross["Account_Name"]]
​
out = (
        cross
           .join(pd.DataFrame(l_matches, columns=["Company_name (match)", "Company_name (Score)"]))
           .drop("Company_name", axis=1).groupby("Account_Name", as_index=False).max()
      )
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  Account_Name   Company_name (match)  Company_name (Score)
0    microsoft  Microsoft corporation              0.533333
1      samsung            samsung Ltd              0.777778
2        tesla           tesla motors              0.588235
```

Comment: i keep on gettign teh folowing error:
MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False